# DAX - Display the top 1 count in a calculated column

Tags: pivot, calculated-columns, dax, frequency-distribution

I have a [Company] column, I have a [Billing day] column in a powerpivot sheet.
A Company can have several different Billing days.

I want to show in a Pivot table, next to the company name, the Billing day with the highest number of occurences.
The tricky part is that the number must appear in a [Calculated Column] that will not be put as a Measure in my Pivot table, but as a Column.
I have reviewed such posts as:
[this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fd84f684-993a-4ffb-bc42-922132437466/get-frequency-max-in-powerpivot?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel) or [this one](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/best-practices-using-summarize-and-addcolumns/).
I have learned much but I am still unable to get the correct values.

Any idea ? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the *best* way to get you what I understand you are asking for, but it is *a* way. I believe it achieves what you want regarding the calculated column.

If I start with this table as Table1:

[image]

Then I add a column using this code: `MaxByDate = COUNTX(FILTER(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Company]=EARLIER(Table1[Company])),Table1[Billing Day]=EARLIER(Table1[Billing Day])),Table1[Billing Day])`

And I add another column using this code: `MaxOverall = MAXX(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Company]=EARLIER(Table1[Company])),COUNTX(FILTER(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Company]=EARLIER(Table1[Company])),Table1[Billing Day]=EARLIER(Table1[Billing Day])),Table1[Billing Day]))`

Then I add one last column using this code: `DateOfMaxOverall = FORMAT(SUMX(FILTER(FILTER(Table1,[Company]=EARLIER([Company])),[MaxByDate]=[MaxOverall]),[Billing Day])/COUNTX(FILTER(FILTER(Table1,[Company]=EARLIER([Company])),[MaxByDate]=[MaxOverall]),[Billing Day]),"m/d/yyyy")`

I get this table:

[image]

Then if I choose to create a Flattened PivotTable from it (Home tab / PivotTable dropdown arrow button / Flattened PivotTable), and set things up like this:

[image]

...and turn off the subtotals and grand totals, I get this:

[image]

Which is, I believe, what you requested.

**But I think a simpler approach might be this:**

Start with the first table (Table1):

[image]

And, using that table as is, create a Flattened PivotTable directly. Then set the PivotTable up like this:

[image]

...and turn off the subtotals and grand totals, to get this:

[image]

...Which you can then filter for the max occurring day for each company:

[image]

[image]

...to get this:

[image]